# Proper way to periodically check an api for new data?

Tags: python, api, rest

I was wondering if there is a proper way to periodically check an api for updated data. I'm looking for a more efficient solution than a while loop with a delay timer.

Are there any standard headers that can be checked to see if content was updated (in order to skip comparing previous results to the new ones?)

**Additional notes**
I using python at the moment but this is a broad question regarding all programming languages.

Comment: You could check out sending a 'HEAD' request. This is like 'GET' except that it only returns the header information like content-length and the date the resource was last modified rather than the entire data set. You can compare that modified date to see if you need to do a full get.

Comment: @Joel If you're going to do that, you may as well issue a full GET with If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since, no?

Comment: The check for the `If-Modified-Since` header works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at the [Conditional Requests spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) and the [Caching spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234).