# Monitor an API for changes - the Pythonic way?

Tags: python, api, rest

I want to be alerted when a RESTful API changes its response.  What's the best way to do this with Python?

I have an API I can call  - `192.168.1.1/status.json` - it returns a JSON file with a bunch of data.  For example :

```
{
  "status"      : "charging",
  "status_code" : 123
}
```

I want to detect when that status code chages.

I can set `cron` to poll the API every minute (which is sufficient resolution for my needs) - but what's the best way to compare the new result with the previous one?

The only thing I can think of is saving the `.json` file to disk, then reading and comparing it.  Is there a better / more correct way to persist data across sessions?

The other alternative is to set the Python program to run as a loop, sleep for 60 seconds and keep the results in memory.  But then I have to make sure there's no memory leak, keep it running at start up, prevent it from crashing, etc.

The API server is very basic - so the suggestion on "[Proper way to periodically check an api for new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022024/proper-way-to-periodically-check-an-api-for-new-data)" isn't possible.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Have you considered [pickleing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html) the data and saving it? It's more pythonic (and probably faster?) than reading a json file and parse-it again.

Answer (score 2):

Mybe you should look at this link. [here](http://ssb.stsci.edu/testing/pandokia/pandokia-1.2rc8/helper_json.html)

```
import json
#import tempfilehttp://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
# first install pandokia  ( pip install pandokia )
import pandokia.helpers.filecomp as filecomp

# string object
obj = """
{
  "status"      : "charging",
  "status_code" : 123
}
"""

objTwo = """
{
  "status"      : "chargingToo",
  "status_code" : 123
}
"""
# From a json back to a python string object
result = json.dumps(obj)
resultTwo = json.dumps(objTwo)

assert filecomp.diffjson( result, resultTwo )
```

Please, read doc after importing the pandokia module. help(filecomp)

Answer (score 2):

[jsondiff](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff) python package will do what you want.

Pull down the latest json from the API, and compare it with the last json using jsondiff. If there have been changes, alert somehow (email etc) and save the new json over the old. Repeat as often as you'd like to check on the API.

jsondiff is easy to use and will give you the changes in the API output for use in your alert.

```
>>> from jsondiff import diff

>>> diff({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 4})
{'c': 4, 'b': 3, delete: ['a']}

>>> diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
{insert: [(3, 'd')]}

>>> diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'])
{delete: [1]}
```